# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionn

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextpane

I want to open a file in jTextPane in read mode. But its giving some exception...
What should I do? 
Should I need to write ActionListner?
I am new to java .. So help me out Friends..
My code is given below..

```
try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BufferedReader input=null;
        File file=new JFileChooser().getSelectedFile();
        /* Line no 524 */input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new  FileInputStream(file)));
        jTextPane1.read(input, "READING FILE :-)");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExcelSheet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

And these are the exceptions

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
at cvparser.ExcelSheet.jButton2ActionPerformed(ExcelSheet.java:524)
at cvparser.ExcelSheet.access$300(ExcelSheet.java:36)
at cvparser.ExcelSheet$4.actionPerformed(ExcelSheet.java:207)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this `File file=new JFileChooser().getSelectedFile();` is simply creating an instance of a `JFileChooser` and asking it to pass back what ever represents a selected file.  But seen as no file has been selected, it is return back `null`...

Try something more like...

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
switch (fc.showOpenDialog(null)) {
    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
        File file= fc.getSelectedFile();
        break;
}
```

Take a look at [How to use file choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details.

**Updated with file reading example**

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
switch (fc.showOpenDialog(null)) {
    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
        File file= fc.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            jTextPane1.read(input, "READING FILE :-)");
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception exp) {
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: It is only an example, add you code that needs to access the `File` within the `APPROVE_OPTION` case...

Comment: okay... but when I open a doc file its showing  some different char  like when we open a doc file in notepad... so is there any solution to that problem?

Comment: `JTextArea` is designed for plain text.  There is no, built in, component that can handle Word documents

Comment: I don't know of any Swing library capable of reading and display a word document, but that's cause I've never really had a need

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
File file=new JFileChooser().getSelectedFile();
```

You're creating a new `JFileChooser` but never showing it to the user, so there's no selected file. The `file` variable will have a null value, which isn't allowed for the argument to the `FileInputStream` constructor.

You need to *display* the chooser to the user and *then* get the selected file... checking that they actually did select a file before you use it. See the [`JFileChooser` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for an example.

Comment: @SiddiqueAnsari: See my edit - the documentation gives a clear example. (Always check the docs first.)